# How to save captured image in custom gallery not in sd card?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-gallery

In my app i have created two activity custom camera and custom gallery.Where custom camera captures image and save it in sd card and works fine but i need to save it in custom gallery not in sd card or default gallery. How to set path to custom gallery so that can view image?

Comment: what is custom gallery here??

Comment: custom gallery is where you can view image within your app

Answer (score -1):

ok for that you have to create arraylist in which you can save path of captured images and make sure that the arraylist should be static and then in next gallery activity you can load image path from arraylist index